# How to put variables into a map in a for loop

Tags: java, loops, nullpointerexception, maps, put

I am attempting to assign keys and values I took from a text file and parsed into variables into a map but it keeps giving me a NullPointeException. When debugging it tells me that they have values when I am assigning them so I am not sure what the problem is. I am passing the scores map from another method where I then write it into a file, I am trying to get the data from a file and put it back into the map.

I have moved it attempted to add the keys and values to the maps at all points that the keys and values have an assignment.

```
for (int index = score.indexOf("=") - 1; index >= 0; index = score.indexOf("=", index + 1)) {
    int j = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int l = 1;
    int k = 2;
    String key = null;
    int value = 0;
    score = score.replaceAll("\\=", "");
    while (j < score.length() && i <= score.length() && l < score.length() && k <= score.length()) {

        if (score.substring(j, i).matches("[^0-9]") || score.substring(l, k).matches("[1-9]")) {

            key = score.substring(j, i);
            if (score.substring(l, k).matches("[1-9]")) {
                String v = score.substring(l, k);
                value = Integer.parseInt(v);
            }

            if (key.matches("[^0-9]") && !key.matches("\\s")) {
                System.out.println(key); //For testing if variable is there
                System.out.println(value); // testing if variable is there.
                scores.put(key, value); // NPE here
           }
```

Expected map to contain new keys and values from file, getting NullPointerException when it attempts to do it.

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: where does the NPE occur and can you provide some sample input?

Comment: It happens when it gets to scores.put(key, value)

Comment: Have you initialized `scores`?

Comment: Sure,  sample input would be taking in the file with the contents "{@=5, #=1}" I stripped the equal signs, commas, spaces and brackets then used that if statement with regex in it to determine if it is a symbol or a number.

Comment: It is initialized in the top of the class, filled with data in a different method, passed to a method where it writes it to a file and then passes to that retrieve save otherwise, I am going to try moving the call into another method where the map is being used and see if that works.

Comment: It works! I was out of my mind on something and had it intialized in the main method as null. Thank you.